# Performance wise: Is it better to have many tiny ajax php controller scripts or one large one?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, performance

**Which is better in terms of speed/performance?**

To have one large Ajax PHP controller script containing all the php functions for multiple different calls.

or

To have many tiny Ajax PHP controller scripts containing just the php function(s) required for each individual call.

I am thinking in terms of performance and efficiency.

Cheers,
Joe

Edit:: Just to add a bit more information, having all the functions on one script would not reduce the amount of ajax requests made.

Comment: What do you mean by *"Ajax PHP script"*? The Ajax JS files or PHP controllers?

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Comment: You might want to consider if it is easy for you to manage one file or many. Performance, probably won't be any different.

Comment: @iambriansreed. Ok, so the answer is that neither is more effective than the other, and it just boils down to personal preference?

Comment: @joe92 Questions that include `better` or `best` are not the *best* questions for SO. Forums are *best* for those kinds of questions.

Comment: @iambriansreed. Ok, I have edited the question to make it clearer that I was referring to the performance of the scripts, not personal preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a bunch of PHP functions in a single file, which is called every time an AJAX request is made, it would look something like this (I'm asusming):

```
$func = $_GET['function'];

switch($func)
{
    //pick the function to call here
}

function test01() {
    //some stuff
}

function test02() {
    //some stuff
}

// 100 more such functions
```

This would definitely be slower (though probably not significantly). The additional overheads in a single large file:

- Parsing a larger file take longer
- The switch statement needs to be evaluated in order to know which PHP function to call.

Additionally, maintaining a larger file can be more difficult. I usually go with single-action PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

From information I have read it is better (performance wise) to minimise the amount of requests the clients browser has to send. I would recommend putting all your functions in one script.

Comment: Putting all the functions in the same script would not minimize the amount of requests I have to send. It would just mean all the requests were going to one larger script. Would you say the same thing knowing this information?

Comment: Yes, assuming you are only firing ajax request as and when needed, then they are 'essential' requests. What I am referring to is the initial load time of the page. It will be reduced by accessing just one file rather than many tiny files.

Comment: Actually, I can't tell what you mean from your question, I assumed (wrongly) that you were referring to js files not php files. If you are using multiple php files then I don't think it matters as it is done server side and wont affect the clients experience.